# Rails - Object in has_many relation is not getting updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a table called Groups, where Groups and Sub-Groups are saved. A group has_many sub-group. Below is the code:

```
groupone.rb (one of the main group)

    class GroupOne < BaseGroup
      belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'GroupOne'
      has_many :sub_group_one, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :groupone
    end

   reports_controller.rb

    class ReportsController < ActionController::Base

      def process_report
        current_record = load_from_xml(xml_path)
        current_group = current_record.last
        base_report_group = find_or_create_base_group(current_group)
        process_sub_group(current_group, base_report_group)
        base_report_group.save

      end

      def process_sub_group(current_group, base_report_group)
        if current_group.sub_group_one.present?
          current_group.sub_group_one.each do |sub_group|
            sgroup = base_report_group.sub_group_one.find_or_initialize_by(group_type_id: sub_group.group_type, serial_num: sub_group.serial_num)
            sgroup.attributes = {name: "Rob", age: 12}
          end
        end
      end

    end
```

The above code is creating new `GroupOne` and many `sub_group_one` records with out any issues but when I try to update the existing `sub_group_one` values, they are not getting updated. For example `{name: "Rob", age: 12}` is not getting updated to any of the sub-group record. I noticed that the new attributes are assigned to `sgroup` during the current `sub_group` iteration and once all the `sub_group` iteration are completed, when I do `binding.pry` for `base_report_group.sub_group_one` it shows the old record and this is the issue.

Can any one please help me to fix this?

Comment: I don't see an 'update' method anywhere in this code - you have 'find_or_initialize_by' assigned to `sgroup` but you don't do anything with `sgroup` after that.  And the code above is missing an `end` statement to close the `if` in the `process_sub_group` function.  But neither of these things should be in the controller - you should move them to the Report model or create a helper class to process these changes.

Comment: @tgmerritt I am saving the main Group here -> base_report_group.save. While saving the main record does the sub-records will not be saved? Using the same code while creating new object, it is creating the GroupOne record  and sub_group_one records but when updating it is not working.

Comment: In `process_sub_group`, save it using `sgroup.save! ` al last after assign attributes